# I lost all data in my tables when I update my models

Tags: ef-code-first

I use EF Code First in my solution with SQL Server Express behind it. When I update my model, I always have to delete my database before restarting my solution. I know this is because my database is no more up to date. In that case, I lose all data in my tables.

I would like to be able to update my models (for example: adding a new field) and keeping all data in my tables.

Even if I update manually my database, when I restart the solution, I get the error below:

**The model backing the 'EntityFrameworkDbContext' context has changed since the database was created. Either manually delete/update the database, or call Database.SetInitializer with an IDatabaseInitializer instance**

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: What is manually? If you add a new table with SQL commands, the hash is not changed and so your model is still valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the creation of EdmMetadata table as follows.

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<IncludeMetadataConvention>();
    }
}
```

This way you can manually update the database without getting the error.

You can check out [Code First Migrations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/09/21/code-first-migrations-alpha-3-no-magic-walkthrough.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

To expand a bit on my comment. This is not generally possible, nor was CF designed for this. The only way around is to manually update your tables with SQL commands AND to update the database model verification hash stored as EDMmetadata or some such in your database, before you live an update your Code first model.

To get the proper hash value you can create a temporary database and just copy your value from there.

Not pretty, but it works.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. When I create a temporary database, where can I found the hash value generated for this database?